# how to insert utf8 characters into oracle database using robotframework database library

Tags: sql, database, utf-8, robotframework

I have a robot script which inserts some sql statements from a sql file; some of these statements contain utf8 characters. If I insert this file manually into database using navicat tool, everything's fine. But when I try to execute this file using database library of robot framework, utf8 characters go crazy!

This is my utf8 included sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE" VALUES (2, 'تست1');
```

This is how I use database library:

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params     cx_Oracle   ${dbConnection}
Execute Sql Script      ${sqlFile}
Disconnect From Database
```

This is what I get in the database:

```
������������ 1
```

I have tried to execute the SQL file using `cx_Oracle` directly and it's still failing! It seems there is a problem in the original library. This is what I've used for importing SQL file:

```
import cx_Oracle
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, sid)
    db = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dsn_tns)
    sql_commands = open(sql_file_addr, 'r').read().split(";")
    cr = db.cursor()
    for command in sql_commands:
        if not command in ["", "\t", "\n", "\r", "\n\r", "\r\n", None]:
            print "Executing SQL command:", command
            cr.execute(command)

    db.commit()
```

I have found that I can define character-set in the connection string. I've done it for `mysql` database and it the framework successfully inserted UTF8 characters into database; this is my connection string for MySQL:

```
database='db_name', user='db_username', password='db_password', host='db_ip', port=3306, charset='utf8'
```

But I don't know how to define character-set for Oracle connection string. I have tried this:

```
'db_username','db_password','db_ip:1521/db_sid','utf8'
```

And I've got this error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: I don't know robotframework, but I solve a similar issue with oci_connect string in PHP, by using `AL32UTF8` as the fourth argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Yu Zhang suggested, I read discussion in this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/502949) and I found out that I should set an environment variable `NLS_LANG` in order to have a `UTF-8` connection to the database. So I've added below line in my test setup:

```
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Would any of links below help?

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm#i1006779
http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=39575
https://community.oracle.com/thread/502949
```

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I have problem with robot framework, not oracle! I can insert utf8 characters into database, but when I execute my sql file through robot scripts, characters are not imported successfully.

Comment: Thanks, I tried solutions in your links again and finally one of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several problems in here...

The first problem might be that you don't save the test files using UTF-8 encoding.

Robot framework expects plain text test files to be saved using UTF-8 encoding, yet most text editors will not save by default using UTF-8.

Verify that your editor saves that way - for example, by opening the file using NotePad++ and choosing Encoding -> UTF-8

Another problem might be the connection to the Oracle database. It doesn't seem like you can configure the connection custom properties to explicitly state UTF-8

This means you probably need to state that the database schema itself is UTF-8

Comment: It was related to the connection properties and even though I couldn't figure out how to set connection character set for oracle connection, your answer saved my time! But I think it's better to wait until someone finds out the final solution!