# Robotframework's databaselibrary returns question marks (?) instead of the actual characters in case of cyrillic characters

Tags: database, oracle, robotframework

Im querying an oracle DB with robotframework-databaselibrary's Query method.
The result contains question marks (?) instead of the actual characters in case of cyrillic characters. If I run the same query using SQL Developer the results are fine. 
The character encoding in the DB is **CL8MSWIN1251**.

I tried using Oracle's CONVERT function to convert the result to **CL8MSWIN1251** before returning. Like this

```
convert(b.surname,'CL8MSWIN1251') AS surname
```

I tried decoding the result string in robotframework using Decode String to Bytes but it does not support the above mentioned encoding.

```
@{queryResults}=    Query   ${sqlQuery}
Log List    ${queryResults}
```

I expect the output to be some cyrillic characters and the actual result is something like this ??????

Comment: See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310396/how-to-insert-utf8-characters-into-oracle-database-using-robotframework-database/34150235) for how to set your client-side NLS_LANG variable, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i managed to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kfinity comment helped me to solve this issue.

I had to set the **NLS_LANG** environment variable to **RUSSIAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251**.
This solved the issue that the query returned question marks.
After this I used the following code to turn the bytes into the appropriate characters

```
 ${string}=  Decode Bytes To String  ${bytes}    windows-1251
```